# Is it legal to activate nested unions via the address of their members?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following code legal (in c++11/14)?

```
bool foo() {
  union bar { int i; bool b; };
  union baz { char c; bar b; };
  auto b = baz{'x'};
  auto barptr = &b.b;
  auto boolptr = &barptr->b;
  new (boolptr) bool{true};
  return b.b.b;
}
```

This example is silly, but I'm playing around with a variadic `variant` implementation that uses nested unions instead of a `char []` block for the variant members, and allowing this will make my current attempt at the copy constructor cleaner.

To break it down into two subquestions:

1. Is the assignment of `boolptr` by accessing a member of `barptr` legal even though `b.b` is inactive?
2. Does the in-place construction of `boolptr` activate `b.b` and `b.b.b`?

References to the standard would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe partially answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined

Comment: Is there any specific reason to assume that the expression `b.b` is more legal than `*(&(b.b))` ? Because otherwise it's fairly obvious that both are equally legal (Nobody is seriously going to argue that `b.b` is _less_ legal!)

Answer (score 2):

As with so many questions about unions and type-punning, it's unclear if your program has defined behavior although I strongly expect it to behave as expected in any sane implementation. What I *can* say with certitude is that [this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7451b47c02fc3b56):

```
#include <memory>
#include <new>

template <typename T>
inline void destruct(T& t) { t.~T(); }

template <typename T, typename...Args>
inline void construct(T& t, Args&&...args) {
  ::new((void*)std::addressof(t)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename T>
inline void default_construct(T& t) {
  ::new((void*)std::addressof(t)) T;
}

bool foo() {
  union bar { int i; bool b; };
  union baz { char c; bar b; };
  auto b = baz{'x'};
  destruct(b.c);
  default_construct(b.b);
  construct(b.b.b, true);
  return b.b.b;
}
```

is standard-compliant, has exactly the effects you desire, and [compiles to exactly the same assembly as the original program in modern compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dca92ebe08987d34). [Original](http://goo.gl/widmXO):

```
foo():
    movl    $1, %eax
    ret
```

[Guaranteed-compliant](http://goo.gl/ewriqD):

```
foo():
    movl    $1, %eax
    ret
```

Comment: Interesting, but pretty useless.  There is no shortage of programs that get optimized away completely, leaving only `return 1;`

Comment: How did `Args` template argument to `default_construct` get deduced?  It's not used in a deducible context.

Comment: @BenVoigt Clang doesn't complain about `Args` either, could both clang and gcc have the same bug?

Comment: Maybe it's being explicitly provided, as an empty list?  In any case, it is better without the unneeded parameter pack.

Comment: I've upvoted this as it surely does work, but it doesn't really answer my original question so I'm going to leave it unaccepted.